# Conditionally rendering component in router view

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on **Vue3** and I'm new to `VueJS`.  So I have an `App.vue` component by default where all components rendering, but I have a `Login.vue` and I don't want to render the `<header></header>` part for the `login.vue`. Consider `Login.vue` as a static component!

**App.vue**

```html
<template>
      <header >
        <img alt="Vue logo" class="logo" src="@/assets/logo.svg" width="125" height="125" />

        <div class="wrapper">
          <HelloWorld msg="Knowledge Base System for IFIC Bank" />

          <nav>
            <RouterLink to="/">Home</RouterLink>
            <RouterLink to="/about">About</RouterLink>
            <RouterLink to="/login">login</RouterLink>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>

    <RouterView/>
</template>
```

Comment: Do you need some kind of layout?

Comment: I just want to render `Login.vue` without `header`  in url `http://localhost:3000/login`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is to use the meta of your route. This way, the solution is reusable in other contexts and not specific to the login route.

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/login',
      component: Header,
      meta: { hideHeader: true }
    }
  ]
})
```

and add a `v-if` with `!route.meta.hideHeader`

```js
<script setup>
    import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
    let route = useRoute();
</script>

<template>
  <header v-if="!route.meta.hideHeader">
    <img alt="Vue logo" class="logo" src="@/assets/logo.svg" width="125" height="125" />

    <div class="wrapper">
      <HelloWorld msg="Knowledge Base System for IFIC Bank" />

      <nav>
        <RouterLink to="/">Home</RouterLink>
        <RouterLink to="/about">About</RouterLink>
        <RouterLink to="/login">login</RouterLink>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
export default {
  setup() {
    let route = useRoute();
    return { route };
  }
};
</script>
```

or setup

```
<script setup>
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
let route = useRoute();
</script>
```

And then your template

```
<template>
  <header v-if="route.path !== '/login'">
    <img alt="Vue logo" class="logo" src="@/assets/logo.svg" width="125" height="125" />

    <div class="wrapper">
      <HelloWorld msg="Knowledge Base System for IFIC Bank" />

      <nav>
        <RouterLink to="/">Home</RouterLink>
        <RouterLink to="/about">About</RouterLink>
        <RouterLink to="/login">login</RouterLink>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

<RouterView/>
```

Use `useRoute`, return it in your setup function.

Now you can use `route.path` and an `v-if`

Comment: Yes its works for me, but I have the `setup` attribute in the `script` tag and then I follow the code it shows an error!

Comment: @Momin i didnt know. You didnt provide your script

Comment: It's okay, You and @fchancel code work for me!

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the header into a component and pass it down into the other components. There you could either use the header component or not.

Comment: Why should I extract `<header>` I have so many pages where all pages have some common layout except `Login.vue`